# Min-height 100% stops at bottom

Tags: html, css

I have my heights set up properly so that it will stretch to the bottom, but it will not stretch passed the bottom, it simply stops and other content stretches beyond it.

If you take my code and put it in, you will see what I mean.

HTML:
http://pastebin.com/ScvdB4zs

CSS:
http://pastebin.com/mxrZ6Gd9

Comment: What is your question, specifically?  You would like the container to expand with the content?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to stretch down with the rest of the content, I don't want any white space on the left side. I was going to do something with position:fixed; but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: You mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337741/min-height-100-stops-at-bottom ?

Comment: No, I mean your actual page.  Pastebin is something, but if you could do us all a favor and link to your actual page, that'd be much more helpful.  If you don't have it up somewhere, try http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nFrRd/

Comment: Why are people even downvoting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I would simply just take out the min heights and change the heights of both the .nav and the .dashboard to whatever you want. It is much more customizable. And just a suggestion: I would make the dashboard a certain percent, just so then people with a different size screen can have the same aesthetic pleasure.

Comment: That's probably what I'm going to go with. This is for an admin panel anyway, so it's mostly just for a few people.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an overflow to your nav div to extend the contents

```
.nav { 
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:#153E7E; 
    height:500px; 
    min-height:100%; 
    width:250px; 
    border-right:5px solid #151B54; 
    float:left; 
}
```

Comment: That made the div itself have a scroll bar.